# Access window.console after overwrite

Tags: javascript, console

Is it possible to somehow access to console.log after it gets overwritten?

```
window.console = { log: function (msg) { alert(msg); }, /* etc... */ };
```

Would be it be possible to regain the original console.log functionality?

Comment: What is the original? Firebug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can back up the console before overwriting it.

```
var oldConsole = window.console;
window.console = { log:function(msg){alert(msg)} //...};
```

Then you can use the `oldConsole` variable.

```
oldConsole.log('test');
```

If you can't back it up, you can create an iFrame, and then steal the console from there (this may not work in all browsers):

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(i);
window.console = i.contentWindow.console;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcG7E/2

Comment: The answer below (delete window.console) is more useful. I'd say it should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat the idea of stealing console from an iframe is a pretty nice hack!

Comment: The solution with iFrame is epic and exactly what I have needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Edit** (2017-04-08): This advise is outdated, in Firefox 52 and Chrome 57 `console` is no longer defined on the window prototype and deleting it will really delete it.

---

At least with the `console` object defined by Firefox and Chrome, you can simply delete the overwritten property to restore the original one:

```
window.console = {};
delete window.console;
window.console.log("This works!");
```

This works as if the `console` property were defined on the prototype of the `window` object - except that it isn't, the browsers are doing some magic here.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: @RelaXNow: Indeed, this advise expired. I added a note on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Except if whoever has overwritten it has included some code to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var customLog = {
    oriLog: '',
    Log: function(){
        // create string to display
        var displaystring = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            displaystring += arguments[i];
            if (i + 1 != len) 
                displaystring += ', ';
        }
        alert(displaystring);
        customLog.oriLog(arguments);
    }
}
window.onload = function(){
    if (console != null) {
        customLog.oriLog = console.log;
        console.log = customLog.Log;
    }

}
```