# console.log - Chrome extension doesn't execute console.log, it just skips console.log

Tags: google-chrome-extension, console.log

My Chrome extension doesn't seem to execute `console.log` in any way. It skips it.

`console.log` works: I can open the Console, type `console.log('test');` and it works. It works from other scripts, i.e. a JS script loaded in a HTML page locally, but not from my extension.

My `background.js` that I run through `manifest.json` below. It executes `alert()`, but not `console.log`

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-3.0.0.min.js" }, function() {

      console.log('----');

      alert('Hello!);

  });
});
```

I've tried:

- `delete console.log`, `delete window.console` and `delete window[console]` as suggested by [Restoring console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089443/restoring-console-log/7089671#7089671) and [JavaScript console log in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080610/javascript-console-log-in-magento/21954826#21954826), but no success.
- loaded the extension in Incognito mode, with no other extensions loaded, but no success.
- updated `background.js` to consist of only a single line - `console.log('----');` - still doesn't work.
- making sure that the console reports "All", not just errors.

My `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Chrome Extension",
  "description": "This extension will you save time.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Click to start the extension"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }

}
```

Comment: Background page, popup page, web page all are separate windows and have their own console. Background page console can be opened on chrome://extensions page when [x] Developer mode is enabled. I believe this question was asked many times.

Comment: @wOxxOm _"I believe this question was asked many times."_ You are not wrong.

Comment: Actually the issue was from not running the `executeScipts` in my background.js. By doing so, I've included console logs in the active window console.

Answer (score 5):

The console for your extension is in a separate window.You can inspect your `console.log()` messages by:

1. Go to `chrome://extension`
2. Enable developer mode
3. Click on the "background page" link at the "Inspect views" line
4. The developer console for your extension will open here.

Credits to: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: It just logs the background js file not from the popup js. what is the solution

Comment: I can not see any link for "background page" inside inspect views. There's is only "No active views" inside inspect views.