# Firebug console doesn't print-out anymore

Tags: firefox, console, firebug

All happened suddenly... 2 weeks ago..., the Firebug console stopped prompt me messages - all messages are not logged and it's doesn't matter if it's error/warning or info.
I Googled it all over and found that the Firefox console itself saying this message:

> The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

But, my app does not override the console global object in any way and also, it occurs in any website I'm in - the console doesn't show noting except the HTTP outgoing requests I choose it to show me.
I'm sure it's Firebug's issue, I tried to downgrade Firebug to 1.11.x, it works for me 2 hours and the problem has back again.

I'm using: Firefox 23.0.1 and Firebug 1.12.1

Comment: Do you have something like this in your code `var console = ...` Don't redefine console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212373/firefox-web-console-disabled

Comment: You may have enabled the new built-in Firefox dev tools console (CTRL_SHIFT_K). Also, create a new Firefox profile and try on a clean profile to see it the problem persists.