# Why does my jQuery.get return null

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use the following code

```
var searchUrl = config.searchUrl +'?lat='+center[0].geometry.location.lat()+'&lng='+center[0].geometry.location.lng()+'&'+Object.toQueryString(params);
jQuery.get(searchUrl, {}, function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
    alert(searchUrl);
});
```

when i use what is outputted by `alert(searchUrl);` which looks like this

> http://website.com/Current-Build/stores/index/search/?lat=-37.5636495&lng=143.8671868&radius=30&distance_unit=km

in the browser it outputs XML like this

```
<results>
    <markers>
        <marker marker_label="1" location_id="953"/>
        <marker marker_label="2" location_id="952"/>
    </markers>
    <storelist><div class="store-list transparent-header">list</div></storelist>
</results>
```

however, `alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));` outputs null, is there something i'm doing wrong with my request/response

NOTE: what i am trying to do is replace the original use of GDownloadUrl that was use in this script, at this point all i'm trying to do is get the response and confirm it's the same as what i am seeing in the browser

Comment: What does data alert to in your success function? I am wondering if the issue is that you are trying to stringify an XML string.

Comment: Does the URL you're trying to get the XML from have the same domain as the page calling it, as in are they both on the same site.

Comment: If `data` is an XML document, you wont be able to JSON-stringify it. Try to `console.log()` it to see what it really is.

Comment: @adeneo yeh their the same domain, the page the javascript call is made on is http://website.com/Current-Build/stores/

Comment: Well, I think @Bergi nailed it, you can't stringify XML as it's not JSON, and it's probably already a string.

Comment: @Bergi is there something else i can use other than `console.log()` as one thing that keeps coming up in the console for firefox and chrome is _The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page._, that's the reason why i use `JSON.stringify` as that output the contents of objects

Comment: What? Simply remove the script that [overwrites `console`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212373/firefox-web-console-disabled) then.

Comment: @Bergi since i'm building on Magento it took me a while to find out where to remove the script, all it's showing me in the console is [object XMLDocument] but when i parse that with `jQuery.parseXML` it then returns null, i need to see what's inside the xml just to make sure that it's what i'm expecting

Comment: Why not open Chromes network tab, look at the response and request sections? It should show it. F12 > Network > Find the request on the left and click on it > Click Response tab on right.