# Why does Firebug not show an 'Uncaught Type Error' for undefined properties?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, error-reporting

I typically use Firebug for development, but lately some of my scripts have been failing silently. After hours of tracking down the error, I discovered I was attempting to get a property of an undefined variable. The console had no errors, the page just "broke". However, in the Chrome DevTools it correctly identifies the error. here is a simple test case:

```
var x = {
    i: {a:1,b:2}
}
```

In Chrome you get

```
console.log(x.i.a); //1
console.log(x.iii.a); //Uncaught TypeError: 
                      //Cannot read property 'a' of undefined 
console.log('finished'); //does not execute
```

In Firebug you get

```
console.log(x.i.a); //1
console.log(x.iii.a); //(nothing)
console.log('finished'); //does not execute
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qancd1o7/10/).

So in a real script, when this happens, I have a seriously hard time tracking down where my script is halting, and I have to add a huge amount of console logging just to narrow down the error.

**Is this a bug, or somehow the intended behavior of Firebug, or maybe there's a setting I can tweak?** I'm using 2.0.3.

Comment: native Firefox debugger shows the error just fine.

Comment: firebug takes over the normal console (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212373/firefox-web-console-disabled) so I can't use it, nor do I want to.

Comment: It is not that bad anymore... :) File a bug with Firebug if you think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the option *Show JavaScript Errors* within the [*Console* panel options menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).

[image: Show JavaScript Errors option]

As you can see, this makes the console correctly log the error message.