# Can't iterate over array in certain pages

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this simple array:

```
var a = new Array();
a.push(o);
```

When running this code:

```
a.forEach(function(o){console.log(o)});
```

In a blank page - I can see the object being logged to the console.

The thing is - I have this code running in a another page and
The foreach loop does not log anything, even though I can see the object in a[0].

I suspect this may has to do with the Prototype JS lib that this page utilizes- though I wasn't able to prove it.

Does that sound familiar?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is `o`? When exactly do you run that code? What other code is running?

Comment: Not sure that it Would help, since I can't attach the problematic page.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype replaces console log messages, [use this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089443/restoring-console-log) to see the actual console log:

```
delete console.log
```

After this console messages will appear.

Comment: God knows why. Thanks.