# How to restore console.log on a web page that overwrites it?

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

Twitter’s website does something like

```
console.log = function () {};
```

to turn the browsers’ built-in `console.log` method into a no-op. Is there I way to restore the original function?

Comment: use `delete console.log`

Comment: Is console.dir() or console.warn() useable?

Comment: @michael Only `console.error`…

Comment: What if the site overwrites the entire console with `console = { log: function () { } };`?

Comment: see this [restoring-console-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089443/restoring-console-log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they also removed it in the prototype, getting the `log` method using  [`getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) should work:

```
console.log = Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log;
```

Since using `console.log = function() {}` overrides, but doesn't remove the one defined in the prototype, you can delete the overriding method:

```
delete console.log
```

Comment: Or just `console.log = Console.prototype.log` 

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - try this in chrome please :)

Comment: Please remove others name from your answer. It isn't comment

Comment: It's not a comment, it's a credit. I thought of just deleting the overriding method, and then noticed your comment. I can remove it, if it bothers you.

Comment: @OriDrori I’m curious why Chrome decided to not expose `Console` to the global scope.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - please tell me when you find out.

Comment: not working on Firefox 52. Even when console.log is present, Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log == undefined. It seems the prototype is just a generic object.