# window.MutationObserver is null in web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, mutation-observers

I want to detect the DOM changes using `MutationObserver` on web page `https://www.baidu.com/` in Tampermonkey script in Chrome.

When I refer to `MutationObserver` in the Tampermonkey script, it is always null. It seems the original js script in the web page sets `MutationObserver` to null.

Is there a way to recover `MutationObserver` so I can use the feature normally?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a particular site that overrides window.MutationObserver or you have an extension that does the same in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: If it's `null`, it appears that something is directly setting it to that value.

Comment: `MutationObserver`has been supported in Chrome for years. If you're getting `null` for `MutationObserver`, something has either overwritten it or shadowed it. If you're getting `null` for `window.MutationObserver`, something has overwritten it or shadowed `window`. In either case, it's specific to the page/environment where you're doing this, it's not a general thing using Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm @VLAZ You are right! When I run a Tempermonkey script on a website, the `MutationObserver` is always `null`. It must be something wrong with the Tempermonkey extension.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, `MutationObserver` works normally on other websites. Seems like the specific web page itself (https://www.baidu.com) sets the `MutationObserver` to `null`. Is there a way to recover the `MutationObserver`?

Comment: Restore it via iframe: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089553).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! fixed using this method.