# window.alert and confirm work, but not prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a Javascript prompt for the user to enter data (as prompts are used for). But, it won't show. window.alert shows, and so does window.confirm. But, not prompt.
Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
var is_expired = document.getElementById("is_expired").value;
    if (is_expired == "yes") {
        alert(is_expired);
        var answer = prompt("Are you sure you?");
        alert(answer);
    }
```

When this runs, the if statement is entered. The first alert displays "yes" as it should. But, then, it skips the prompt line. The next alert displays saying "Undefined".

Now, if the only thing I change is the keyword prompt, it will work, as such:

```
var is_expired = document.getElementById("is_expired").value;
    if (is_expired == "yes") {
        alert(is_expired);
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you?");
        alert(answer);
    }
```

When I run this, the confirm box appears. If I click Okay, then the next alert says "true" and if I click Cancel the alert says "false".

So, the big takeaway here is that there isn't a syntax error that's causing the Javascript to stop. It's actually skipping over that single line and continuing execution. What's wrong with that line? I've checked multiple sites to ensure it's correct. 
Adding the second "default" parameter does not help either. I tried that. Also, There are no Javascript errors to indicate the problem.

I went [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt) and changed it to my code (I hardcoded is_expired to be yes), and it works there.

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not relying on W3school's example to be accurate, I used their "try it out" page to test my own code. I also did this on jfiddle and it worked fine. Using the console to check the function returns "undefined".

EDIT2: Actually, scratch that. I accidentally hit enter again when there was no command in the console. The actual output for prompt is:

```
[12:07:55.940] [object Function]
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zDZQK/. What browser are you using? Can you reproduce the problem on jsFiddle?

Comment: What other JavaScript is on the page?  Do you have any libraries that may be overriding the `window.prompt` method?  What does `console.log(window.prompt)` show?

Comment: any warnings in the console? console.log(window.prompt)

Comment: Do an `alert(window.prompt);` - what does it show?

Comment: try console.log for what the computer receives ( `console.log(is_expired)` )

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: He's just using their example, plus he probably didn't know.  That doesn't deserve a -1.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Hover over the downvote button and read the text: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`. This question does not meet that criteria and does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: @JoeFrambach if its linked to w3schools it should be labeled `This question ruins any research effort; it is unclear, confusing, and misleading`

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: His link shows he did try to research it.  w3schools seems to have high google ranks, so it probably appeared in his search.  He didn't know it wasn't "good".  He's just using their "example" to show that if you run the code, it works.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i will remove `-1` if he removes it, and add `+1` if he changes it to a reliable site,  its links like this that make it rank high on the google search. please also express that the link should be removed and that w3schools is a bad resource.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight You're missing the point of the SO downvote. It is not to police Google search ranking. It's not to punish a lack of knowledge of the questioner (otherwise *every* question should be downvoted to oblivion by virtue of being a question). It's to indicate a poorly constructed question on a Q&A site. This question is not poorly constructed by far. No one here is arguing against your claim that W3Schools sucks (most people agree, myself included). They're pointing out your misuse of one of SO's tools.

Comment: The reason I linked W3schools, is because I changed that existing code to mine to test it, and it worked fine. I didn't link it to say I was using their example. It works in jfiddle. It works everywhere but my page. When I go to the console and type window.prompt("test"), all I get is undefined. If I run that same command on any other page, a prompt shows.

Comment: Sorry for the double post. When I do alert(window.prompt) I get "function prompt(s)

{   window.status = s

}" Which I guess isn't right?

Comment: @Troncoso: There's your problem!  Something replaced the built-in `prompt` command with `window.status = s`!  Do you have any idea where that could be coming from?  What libraries/other JavaScript is on your page?

Comment: I see. I don't. Luckily there is only about 500 files spread across about 50 different directories to look through. Actually I did find it. Is there anyway to override it again? I don't want to remove it as I'm not sure if it's being used by something else (I didn't write the original application)

Comment: @Troncoso You'd have to have a reference to the original, native `prompt` before the override happens in order to re-override it. As Rocket Hazmat suggests, you can use some file searching magic to find it far faster than manually searching.

Comment: @Troncoso: There are a few things you can try.  `delete window.prompt;` should remove that override and replace the original method.  If not, you can try to "steal" it from an iframe.  See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7081490 (just replace `console` with `prompt`) :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sweet, the `delete` trick works, but I tried it in Chrome. Will that work in all browsers?

Comment: @ajp15243: I have no idea! :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat delete doesn't work for me. But, that iframe thing did the trick. I saved and restored what is the current prompt to ensure anything using that function doesn't break. Thanks for the help! If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Troncoso: Glad that method worked; I added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, something in your code has overridden the `window.prompt` method with `function prompt(s) { window.status = s }`.  Not sure if this was intentional or not.

There are a few methods you can use to "restore" the original `prompt`.

1. You can backup the original at the very start of your page:

   ```
   var originalPrompt = window.prompt;
   // Whatever code is on your page
   function prompt(s) { window.status = s }
   ```

   Then use `originalPrompt` instead:

   ```
   var answer = originalPrompt("Are you sure you?");
   ```
2. You can `delete window.prompt;` (or set `window.prompt = null;`), though this may not work in all browsers.
3. You can create an iframe (which creates a new `window` environment), and then "steal" the `prompt` from there.

   ```
   var i = document.createElement('iframe');
   i.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(i);
   window.prompt = i.contentWindow.prompt;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`prompt` should pretty much work in every browser. One possibility is to check if you didn't accidently override this function somewhere in your source. If you type `prompt` in the browserconsole when on your site, it should state something like this:

```
> prompt
function prompt() { [native code] }

// or put in your code:
alert(window.promt);
```

Otherwise it got overridden somehow (most likely by forgetting the `var` keyword):

```
> prompt = function(){alert("foo!")}
> prompt
function (){alert("foo")}

// calling prompt() would now pop an alert box
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring variables in a function, make sure you use the `var` keyword so it doesn't clobber the global namespace. It sounds like you're doing this somewhere:

```
function my_thing() {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    prompt = "What the heck";
}
```

Omitting the `var` keyword puts `prompt` in the global namespace, clobbering the default `prompt` function.

Comment: according to his question, it seems to be overridden by a function, otherwise the second alert would not pop up but rather throw a TypeError.

Comment: @Christoph: Though it's probably for the same reason.  Let's say he did `function prompt(){}` or `prompt = function(){};`